# How to put notifications for ios with cordova-phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, push-notification

My company is building its mobile app. Do you know if setting notifications for a mailling system in the app is possible? like the facebook chat who notifies you when you have a new message on your phone. 
For the moment the answer seems to be 'no, but you could do it in native'. Is it true? is there anything (plugins, ...) to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, i've found this : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

The developpers said that wasn't possible, but here it is, it's possible.